# Getting the encryption/has algorithm used for modem configuration file

Tags: hash, passwords

Hello guys I have backed up my modem configuration file and found the username and password is in clear text; the files shows the username and the password is :

```
password=_DEV_4FC6EA6A****************************
```

how do I get which encryption or hash algorithm is used to generate the given string and how strong it is?

Comment: You could simply ask the modem manufacturer; indicate you require this information to do a security audit.

Comment: The full hash is still visible in the edit history. If you want to get rid of it, you need to [contact](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/contact) the stackexchange team.

Comment: It's ok I messed up some of it before pasting it here !! i'll flag it just to be on the safe side

Comment: @chaosmind I contacted the Stackexchange security team. They'll have to handle this one as site moderators cannot fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot; most (symmetric) encryption routines create output that is indistinguishable from random. This is however more likely to be the output of a password hash. The only thing you can say is that the result is 24 bytes. That 24 bytes hopefully contains a fully random salt (mostly 8 bytes) and a hash or password hash. In that case it's probably MD5 as there are only 16 bytes left. It could also be the output of SHA-224 directly over the password, or a HMAC using SHA-224 or similar with a device specific key.

If it is `salt | MD5` or just `SHA-224` is of course something you could test yourself. You could do this using your own password or - possibly - a dictionary attack. Note however that the password should now be changed ASAP as *anybody* can perform a dictionary attack.

Comment: Great thank you, It is ok I messed up the characters before pasting them here I just kept the format the same

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out how to extract my password (but I didn't understand how the javascript works). Here you go :

> How to extract modem PPPoE username and password:
>
> - Enter Firefox, and in the address bar type: 192.168.1.x (the modem address)
> - the User Name:
>     the Password:
> - On the main page, press: Disconnect
> - On the main page, press: Internet
> - In the address bar paste this:

```
    javascript:
        (function(){  
            var s,F,j,f,i;   
            s = "";   
            F = document.forms;   
            for(j=0; j<F.length; ++j) { 
                    f = F[j]; 
                    for (i=0; i<f.length; ++i) { 
                            if (f[i].type.toLowerCase() == "password")
                                    s += f[i].value + "\n"; 
                    } 
            } 
            if (s) 
                    alert("Kwdikoi pou vrethikan:\n\n" + s); 
            else 
                    alert("Den yparxoun formes kwdikwn s afti ti selida.");
        })();
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. This seems more a modem specific hack than an answer to the question though.

Comment: hmm no not much my question was how to determine and know which encryption or hash algorithm is applied to a sting from the output